# Python dictionaries and select case

Tags: python, dictionary

While trying to implement a switch case like scenario in python using dictionaries I came across a problem.

```
pos=(0,0)
move={'up':(pos[0],pos[1]+1),'dn':(pos[0],pos[1]-1)}
newpos=move['up']
pos=newpos
```

this works just as expected. However when i do something like this.

```
pos=(0,0)
move={'up':(pos[0],pos[1]+1),'dn':(pos[0],pos[1]-1)}
moves_list=['up','up','dn','dn']#or anything else for that matter
for mo in moves_list:
    pos=move[mo]
print pos
```

This piece of code should give me the final position as (0,0)
However I get (0,-1)

I understand that this is because the values for move['up'] and move['down'] are calculated on definition of the dictionary. 
If that is the case,whenever I need to define a computation intensive algorithm for finding the next position, I will be wasting time calculating moves which may never be used.
eg. if move_list is just ['up,'up'] then 'dn' does not need to be calculated.

**My Question**

Is there any way I can prevent the calculation of these values until they are actually called?

Is there a more elegant way of going about switch-case in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally build anonymous functions for the various 'switch cases'.

A anonymous function is created with `lambda`, and follows the syntax `lambda args: return_value`.

So, for example, this function takes a number as input and returns that number plus 1:

```
add_one = lambda x: x + 1
```

Something like this would work:

```
moves = {
        'up': lambda (x,y): (x, y+1),
        'dn': lambda (x,y): (x, y-1),
    }
```

You can then make a move with:

```
pos = moves[move](pos)
```

Note that it's generally a better idea to take explicit arguments into your lambda function.  This allows for clearer and more reusable code.

Comment: Thanks. I had implemented the lambda functions without the arguments after searching. Glad to know that I was using the right thing. Will pass the position as an argument.

Comment: @theSage - to clarify, the reason the arguments are good practice is because it enables you to relocate the definition of `moves` without causing problems.  A lambda without args is 'capturing' the `pos` variable, and will fail if, eg, you only define it once, outside the loop.